# Deadlock occurs on multiple processes trying to insert a new row on the same table

Tags: sql-server, multiprocessing, deadlock

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WKF_EXEC_HTR](
[MODULE_ID] [int] NULL,
[SESSION_ID] [int] NULL,
[Request_id] [int] NULL,
[wkf_exec_htry_seq] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_wkf_exec_htr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [wkf_exec_htry_seq] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) 
  ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WKF_EXEC_HTR]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     [FK_WKF_EXEC_HTR_SESSION_ID] FOREIGN KEY([SESSION_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SESN] ([SESSION_ID])
GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WKF_EXEC_HTR] CHECK CONSTRAINT     [FK_WKF_EXEC_HTR_SESSION_ID]
```

I have a Primary Key and Clustered Index on [wkf_exec_htry_seq]. When multiple processes try to insert in this table it causes deadlock any idea how to avoid this deadlock.

Comment: **Why did you add `ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF` in the definition?** That leaves only table lock as an option. Essentially it's asking for a deadlock - you are asking SQL Server to lock the entire table immediatelly whenever this table is accessed

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Whatever it is, there are other ways to achieve this that don't involve table locks and the unavoidable deadlocks